# Use count data models when the dependent variable is a ranking (with panel data)

Tags: panel-data, count-data, ordered-logit

I am currently writing a Master Thesis about the relationship between academic freedom and World University Rankings (such as ARWU, Times Higher Education, etc). I am using panel data.

My dependant variable is the ranking obtained by each university (going from 1, the highest, to 500, the lowest). Because of the large number of modalities, I read that an ordinal regression model wouldn't be apropriate.

Thus, my supervisor recommended me to try out a count data model. The idea would be to treat the dependent variable as a count variable.

The problem is, I am not very experienced in count models, and most of the ressources I find online are about cross-sectionnal data, and I find nothing about panel data.

Apparently, fixed effects poisson regression is a thing, and I managed to code it in R, but I have no idea if it is appropriate given my data (what should I look for to know this ?).

What diagnosis tests should I conduct in order to know which regression is more appropriate with count data ? If random effects is more appropriate, what is the count data equivalent of such a regression ?

I hope I have been clear enough, thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

A Poisson or similar count model (quasi-Poisson, negative binomial) makes an assumption about the association between the value of a count and the variance in the count. That won't necessarily hold for this type of ranking data.

It's quite possible to perform an ordinal regression with a large number of ordered outcome levels, or even continuous outcomes. See, for example, Chapter 13 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/ordinal.html). The `orm()` function in his R [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) is specifically designed to handle the hundreds of intercepts that arise in such models. The within-university correlations in the panel data might be handled with a robust covariance matrix (produced by the package's `robcov()` function). Harrell also provides [links to further information about longitudinal ordinal modeling](https://www.fharrell.com/post/rpo/#longitudinal-ordinal-models) and how Markov models can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful ! Would you know how I can specify on R that my variable is ordinal in my panel dataframe ? For ordinal variables with a small number of outcomes, I simply use factor() on the variable and I specify the levels. But here, since I have a huge number of outcomes, when I specify all the levels in the factor() command, the variable ends up being "factor with 1 levels". Did it take into account my 107 levels or was there a mistake and does it only think that there is only 1 level ?

Comment: @MullerI. If you use the `orm()` function in the `rms` package you don't need to specify the outcome as a factor. From the help page: "The response variable can be any data type; `orm` converts it in alphabetic or numeric order to a factor variable and recodes it 1,2,... internally."

Comment: And would you know a way to check if the orm() function took into account the fact that my data is in panel form ? I used a database obtained through the pdata.base() command with the plm package, but I'm not sure is the orm() function actually knows that my data is panel, and the guide doesn't seem to specify a way to check that.

Comment: @MullerI. the `orm()` function can handle panel data via a marginal approach and a "woking independence" assumption. You first fit the model without regard to the panel nature of the data. You then can take the model returned by `orm()` and present it to the `robcov()` function along with a "cluster" argument indicating the variable that represents the repeated measures (university, in your case). That adjusts the variance/covariance matrix of coefficient estimates and p-values to account for the repeated measures in the panel data. Point estimates of coefficients don't need to be adjusted.

Comment: @MullerI. you might also consider the Bayesian approach for ordinal regression provided by the `blrm()` function in the R [`rmsb` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rmsb). That could treat University similarly to the way a random effect is handled in a mixed model, in an ordinal regression. I don't have experience with that package, however.